# Is there a way to automate the creation of Google apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I'm creating an app which can be given any available permissions for accessing the user's google account.

Is there some way for the app to create a Google Apps Script for that user, and to set a trigger for that script to run automatically every certain time interval?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your app to run as the user, that's essentially creating a script for the user automatically, if they authorize it.  Yeah, we can program in [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically) too.